# Summing numbers in C

Tags: c, loops

So I have a problem in my C course as follows: Download the file ‘mydatafile’ posted on the web site, transfer the file to the remote Unix machine, and, based on the example ‘running_sum.c’ listed on p.26 of the Kelley-Pohl book, create a C code called ‘processdata.c’ which

- reads (as floats) the numbers from the data file
- present them on the screen in three columns as count positive numbers negative numbers
- counts the number of positive and negative numbers
- computes the sum of all positive numbers and the sum of all negative numbers
- output the results on the screen as

  `I have read … positive numbers, with a sum = …`
  `I have read … negative numbers, with a sum = …`

I have included my code so far.  It runs, but it gives me positive numbers in the negative column and vice versa.  Also, I'm not too sure how to count the number of positives and negatives and their sum.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void)
{
  int i;
  float x, positive, negative;

  if (scanf("%lf", &x) !=1) {
    printf("No data found\n");
    exit(1);}

  positive=negative=x;
  printf("%9s%22s%22s\n",
     "Count", "Positive Numbers", "Negative Numbers");
     printf("%9d%22.3f%22.3f\n",
        1, x, positive,negative);

     for (i=2; scanf("%f", &x) == 1; ++i) {
       if (x>0){
         positive=x;
         negative=0;}
       else if (x<0){
         negative=x;
         positive=0;}
       printf("%9d%22.3f%22.3f\n", i, x, positive, negative);
     }
     return 0;
     }
```

Comment: I actually don't know why I did that.  Now that I removed the x, it works.  Thank you so much for your help

Comment: @Zak (and OP): Homework questions are [fine](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10811/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions), as long as the asker shows that he has done due diligence - present the full problem instead of just a link, show work done so far, give minimal example, etc, etc, all of which OP has done admirably. It is a model question, really, in comparison to even many non-homework ones. That said, it is on the student's head to be aware whether, and to which degree, the school/course considers homework assistance on SO as fair help vs cheating/plagiarism.

Comment: To get the sums, just add something like `int poscount = 0, negcount = 0;` at the start of the program. Then `poscount++` or `negcount++` when you find a positive or negative number. For sums, you'll want `sum += x` or something similar. `sum` will need to be a `float`.

Comment: thanks everyone, also, I was wondering how to have blank space instead of the zeros

Comment: In your output, you want to replace zeros with blanks? You'll need an `if` statement that prints an appropriate number of spaces if the number is zero, and prints the number otherwise. `if (something == 0) printf("    "); else printf("%4d", something)`.

Answer (score 2):

Need to Change

```
printf("%9d%22.3f%22.3f\n", i, x, positive, negative);
```

To

```
printf("%9d%22.3f%22.3f\n", i, positive, negative);
```

This will solve the issue.

Comment: Thanks, I was also wondering how to get blank space instead of zeros.  I tried printf(" "); and it returned 1's

Comment: @Mike Try `\t` it will print tab spaces. for example `printf("%d\t%d", a,b);`